# OS X dylib refers to the executable itself

Tags: c++, mysql, macos, linker, dylib

I'm not sure if I'm asking this question the right way, but I have recently tried to make an application that uses mysql/c++

I compile the program like this:

```
g++ -o test main.cpp -I./include -L./lib -lmysqlclient -lmysqlcppconn
```

and when I run the program it responds the following:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /home/myname/Desktop/path/to/exe
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/Desktop/path/to/./test
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Can anyone seee what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if more info about the problem is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess your mysql libraries are not located in a standard place.
If you want to keep your libraries in a non standard place, you should set the environment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your dynamic link libraries.
Under linux/most unices that would be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

So something like:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:./lib";
./yourExecHere
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I tried so, yet i still get the "library not loaded: /home/myname/Desktop/path/to/exe"

I once mistakenly exported the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to contain this path (that does not exist), but no path seems to hold it now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot se what might be wrong, so I moved all .cpp files to a new folder structure and rewrote the Makefile. I all works now, thanks!